# Button Event Doesn't Call inside CustomView on MAP?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am integrating Map Annotation in my app. I am Adding Annotations on Map as below. All annotations are added successfully on MAP.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "CustomAnnotation"
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"MapTemp")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false

        return annotationView
    }
```

I am showing a customView on click of map annotation. When a annotation is clicked its delegate is called in which custom view is added over map as done in below code-

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)
    {
        if (self.viewCustom != nil)
        {
            self.viewCustom.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View123", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.viewCustom = nib[0] as? UIView

        println(self.viewCustom.viewWithTag(100))


        if let buttonFB = self.viewCustom.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {

            buttonFB.addTarget(self, action:"clickFacebook:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }

        self.addBounceAnimationToView(viewCustom)

        var hitPoint : CGPoint = view.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: viewCustom)

        self.viewCustom!.frame = CGRectMake(-100,-200, 250, 200)

        view.addSubview(self.viewCustom!)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.viewCustom)

    }
```

Inside the custom view I have a button `buttonFB` specified with a tag value and event `clickFacebook`.

```
@IBAction func clickFacebook(sender: AnyObject)
 {
     //Face
 }
```

but on click event of this button does not triggers and only Mapview's delegate `didDeselectAnnotationView` is always called (below method is called).

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)
    {
      //
    }
```

I want the event of the button to trigger. How can I do that.

[image]

darkgray Image is Annotation of MapView and yellow part is button according to image.

Please help me.

Comment: Why not you are going for callout accessory view of map, where you will get accessory button, on click of it, some operation will be performed.

Comment: but I want to Customize All View, And about 5 buttons are added inside view.

Comment: If this is the case,  your yellow view should be an annotation, which will pop up on clicking the image.

Answer (score 0):

As inside `didSelectAnnotationView:` method you are bringing `self.view` to front so `self.view` will be on top which contains map and thus the events will work on the `self view`. Your `self.viewCustom` is below the `self.view` and as you touch the `self.view` handles touches.

You need to bring your `self.viewCustom` to top of the `self.view` only then it will be able to take touches.

You need to change the statement -

`self.viewCustom.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)`

to

`self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.viewCustom)`

Comment: Not, same problem calling didDeselectAnnotationView. Not button event Calling.

Comment: @KiritModi have you changed the above statement?

Comment: Yes, Change as above and try, but same problem.

Comment: @KiritModi have you added button on viewCustom as  viewCustom.addSubview(self.buttonFB!)

Comment: Button added in XIB View and set its Tag = 100.

Answer (score 0):

What is the class of your customview? Do you set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you done with added annotation, come to this method.

And make sure you have custom AnnotationView class to override few methods.

Here is annotation delegate method.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) // use whatever annotation class you used when creating the annotation
    {
        CustomAnnotation *anno = (CustomAnnotation *)annotation;
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"customIdentifier";
        MyAnnotationView *pinView = (MyAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        if (pinView == nil)
            pinView = [[MyAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:anno reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView.canShowCallout = NO;
        pinView.draggable = NO;
        pinView.annotation = anno;

        NSURL *url = //Custom URL and Used SDWebImage to load custom url on UIImageView
        [pinView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-icon.png"]];


        return pinView;

    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Now See `MyAnnotationView` **
***this is key code to achieve this task.***

MyAnnotationView.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@end
```

MyAnnotationView.m

```
#import "MyAnnotationView.h"

@implementation MyAnnotationView

- (nullable UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil) {
        [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGRect newRect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(newRect, point);
    if (isInside == NO) {

        for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {

            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);
            if (isInside == YES) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return  isInside;
}

@end
```

Now here is Select and Deselect method of Annotation View.

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        CustomAnnotation *anno = (CustomAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        NSDictionary *dict = anno.annoDict;

        if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            return;
        }

//This is custom UIView class only with subviews as UILabel, UIImageView, UIButton

        CustomCallOut *callOutView = [[CustomCallOut alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 80.0)];
        [callOutView setupControls];
        callOutView.lblName.text = @"title";


        UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        newButton.frame = callOutView.btnCallOut.frame;
        [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnnextClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [callOutView addSubview:newButton];


        [callOutView setCenter:CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width / 2, -callOutView.bounds.size.height*0.52)];

        callOutView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        [view addSubview:callOutView];

        [mapview setCenterCoordinate:anno.coordinate];
    }
```

**Deselect Method**

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(nonnull MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationView class]]) {
        for (CustomCallOut *subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[CustomCallOut class]]) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is Button Click Event

```
-(void)btnnextClick:(UIButton *)sender {

//Do your stuff

}
```